# How to find your private IP address on DigitalOcean?

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, digital-ocean

i was doing the tutorial on how to set up a node.js application in my virtual server, the problem is , i cannot get my private ip address.

Is it the configuration problem or my droplet in digital ocean is the problem?

So far, i am using ssh to connect, install fail2ban and configure the iptable.

```
curl -w "\n" http://myipAddress/metadata/v1/interfaces/private/0/ipv4/address
<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>
```

That's the configuration that i did while doing the tutorial: how to set up an ubuntu environment and using fail2ban, iptable for firewall purpose

```
-P INPUT ACCEPT
-P FORWARD ACCEPT
-P OUTPUT ACCEPT
-N fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 22 -j fail2ban-ssh
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 80 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j DROP
-A fail2ban-ssh -s 29.248.168.45/32 -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A fail2ban-ssh -j RETURN
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to use the [DigitalOcean metadata API](https://developers.digitalocean.com/documentation/metadata/) to find your private IP address. To reach it, you need to query the metadata service's IP, not your public IP. So the correct command is:

```
curl -w "\n" http://169.254.169.254/metadata/v1/interfaces/private/0/ipv4/address
```

The private interface is designated as `eth1`, so you can also find its IP address with:

```
ifconfig eth1
```

It's also available in the DigitalOcean control panel on your Droplet's settings page:

[image: IP-adder]